# How to export output from command prompt to txt file

Tags: selenium, batch-file, selenium-webdriver, command-prompt, selenium-grid

I downloaded Selenium server (https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/, and run command:
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub >>server.txt`

Log file server.txt is created. However, it is empty. I need to see content of command prompt in this file. I run it on Windows. Any advice? This is content of command promt after executing this command:

[image]

Comment: If it is writing to the console then there is nothing you can do.  But if it is just writing to a different file stream then the answer below should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are various output types. When redirecting everything to file use `&1` as the value of the file descriptor 1. So by using `2>&1` you are redirecting `strerr` to the same output as `stdout` Therefore this should do the trick:

```
(java -ar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub)>server.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank Gerhard.